# Find all natural solutions of $14x+21y=91$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm

> Find all natural solutions of $14x+21y=91$ where $x,y\in \mathbb N$

**My attempt:**

Divided by $7$:

$$2x+3y=13$$

And $\gcd(2,3)=1\mid13$

I found a private solution $x_0=\color{blue}5,\quad y_0=\color{blue}1$

$$2\cdot \color{blue}5+3\cdot \color{blue}1=13$$

So the general solution:

$$\begin{cases}x=5+2t\\
y=1-3t\end{cases}$$

Where $t\in \mathbb Z$

But [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2x%2B3y%3D13)'s answer is diffrent, why?

Comment: (5,1) is a fine solution,  but I get x = 5 + 3t; y = 1-2t.

Comment: 'particular' is a correct replacement for 'private'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WA says
$$
2 + 3k\\
3 - 2k
$$
You say
$$
1 - 3t\\
5 + 2t 
$$
You're close, but wrong, because pugging in $t = 1$, you get 
$$
x = 7\\
y = -2
$$
and
$$
2 \cdot 7 + 3 \cdot -2 \ne 13.
$$

So that's where you went wrong. The difficulty is that it should probably be 
$$
x = 5 - 3t \\
y = 1 + 2t 
$$
instead.

Comment: John is right, since the general solution of a diophantine equation $ax+by=c$ is
$$x=x_{0}-\dfrac{b}{d}\cdot k$$
$$y=y_{0}+\dfrac{a}{d}\cdot k$$
where $d=gcd\left(a,b\right)$ divides $c$.

Answer (score 0):

There are an infinite number of ways to parametrize equations so two sets of equations could both generate the same set.  Your parametrization of the equation is just a different from that WA's.  For your purpose both answers are correct.

Many problems that ask you to parametrize something will give you constraints.  It is often related to the $df/dt$ but these are unique to each area of study.